# Angular-Meteor mongo data not being rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, ionic-framework

I am working on an angular-meteor app and trying to loop through my database to display its data dynamically but am unable to.

Heres my controllers, routes, collections and views.

client/scripts/controllers/stocks.controller.js

```
angular
.module('stockAiApp')
.controller('StocksCtrl', StocksCtrl);

function StocksCtrl($scope, $reactive) {
$reactive(this).attach($scope);

this.helpers({
    nasdaq() {
            return Nasdaqs.find({});
        },
        nyse() {
            return Nyses.find({});
        },
        amex() {
            return Amexs.find({});
        }
});

////////////

}
```

client/scripts/routes.js

```
 .state('tab.stocks', {
        url: '/stocks',
        views: {
            'tab-stocks': {
                templateUrl: 'client/templates/stocks.html',
                controller: 'StocksCtrl as stocks'
            }
        }
    })
```

client/templates/stocks.html

```
<ion-item 
        ng-repeat="stock in stocks.nasdaq" 
        class="item" 
        type="item-text-wrap" 
        href="#">
            <p>{{stock.Symbol}},
               {{stock.Name}},
               {{stock.sector}}</p>
        </ion-item>
```

lib/collections.js

```
Nyses = new Mongo.Collection('nyses');
Nasdaqs = new Mongo.Collection('nasdaqs');
Amexs = new Mongo.Collection('amexs');
```

Comment: can you narrow down the point of failure?

Comment: Very new with angular, however I am not receiving any errors nor is it displaying any data, trying to figure out what direction I should take to figure out what the point of failure actually is.

Comment: what is working as of now? Also how are you getting the data from your database?

Comment: I have the data in my data base already, and I have my collections published. Not sure if I am looping through it incorrectly or something is wrong with my routes/controller code. My routes are currently the only thing that is working.

Comment: your `this.helpers` block looks interesting, are you running on ES6

Comment: Yeah I am running on ES6.

Comment: you are not receiving errors? can you check the browser console

Comment: Checked and double checked, no errors

Comment: ok try replacing `ng-repeat="stock in stocks.nasdaq" ` to `ng-repeat="stock in stocks.helpers.nasdaq" `

Comment: Nothing changed, nor did I get an error.

Comment: wow, im beginning to think your app not be running at all. could you come up with a working example.

Comment: Can you link into a repo with a full app?

Answer (score 0):

try to use .fetch() with the find() method